# Why does my google maps keeps on crashing even though i'm not using it at all?

Tags: google-maps, crashes

So, I'm just using my apps. Then sometimes it freezes for a while, and a notice will pop-up and say "Unfortunately, maps has stopped." even though I'm not using it.

What do I have to do?

Samsung Galaxy S 3

Comment: what apps have you been using?

Answer (score 1):

It could be that you have enable something like Google Latitude tracking, which goes via the Maps app on your phone. Maybe have a look at the settings in your Maps app to see if there is nothing enabled that works in the background, and prevents the application from stopping.

Maybe you have used the application some time before that error? Because Android will not immediately close applications, so it could be that the Maps app is still open from a couple of hours ago.

Maybe some other application is trying to open the Maps application for you? If you for example click on an address or something like that, most apps will try to open your default Maps application. So maybe you have opened/connected to the Maps app without really knowing?